# Parsing a string that has some boolean values back to json (Python)

Tags: python, json, string, python-re

I want to parse a string of JSON back into a JSON. the string has some boolean values.

**Example input:**

str_json = "{'name': 'bob', 'id': '11111', 'happy': True, 'sad': False}"

**Example output:**

d = {"name": "bob", "id": "11111", "happy": "True", "sad": "False"}

**I've tried this:**

```
p = re.compile('(?<!\\\\)\'')
str_json = p.sub('\"', str_json)
d = json.loads(str_json)
```

and got this exception:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 91 (char 90)
```

Comment: `True` and `False` in `str_json` must be lowercase; in yr desired output `"True"` and `"False"` are strings that will both be interpreted as `true` (`bool("False") --> True`). Where did the initial string come from?

Comment: It’s nowhere near JSON to begin with, it’s a Python literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import ast
str_json = "{'name': 'bob', 'id': '11111', 'happy': True, 'sad': False}"

j=ast.literal_eval(str_json)

print(j)
#{'name': 'bob', 'id': '11111', 'happy': True, 'sad': False}
```

Link to document :https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

`ast.literal_eval` is used for evaluating string.

---

Finally convert the boolean values to string:

```
new={k:str(v) for k,v in j.items()}
#output
{'name': 'bob', 'id': '11111', 'happy': 'True', 'sad': 'False'}
```